# documentation using doxygen for visual studio and emacs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, emacs, doxygen

I am trying to use doxygen for document generation from c++ code.

I am using Visual studio 2013 and my team members are using emacs.

Is there any add in that adds suitable commnets (the bulk of it ) automatically from source code?

for example if I have this code:

```
 int myFunc (int x, int y)
 {
       return x+y;
  }
```

it generates the following comments in source code:

```
/*!
 *  myFunc
 * param[in] x
 * param[in] y
*/
```

or something such as this to be filled by me.

Is there any such add on for visual studio? what about Linux?

I am looking for a free one.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but it would seem that the commercial [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) addon can do this. In any case, questions asking for offsite resources are specifically off-topic (but I guess you know that), so voting to close.

Comment: If you use Qt you just need to put `/**` above your function in the header then hit enter and it auto generates all this

Answer (score 0):

For VS2019 you can use [Doxygen Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FinnGegenmantel.doxygenComments). It supports `/*!` and `/**` and is free